# Users vs licenses Google Apps Free

Tags: google-apps, google-workspace

I have a free subscription for Google Apps (grandfathered in), and my user count is increasing beyond 10. On the google help page, it says that I can create 10 free users with my account, but on my admin billing page, it says I have 50 licenses. What exactly is the difference between users and licenses? Can I create 50 emails and assign each to one license?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [G Suite Pricing page](https://gsuite.google.com/pricing.html) (bottom left): *a user is defined as one personalized email address (you@yourcompany). Group email aliases such as sales@yourcompany and support@yourcompany are included in pricing and don't count as additional users.*

A user needs a license to use a Google service, and a single user can have several licenses for diferent tools.

More info about licenses:
https://support.google.com/a/answer/6309862?hl=en

Hope this helps :)